# Bootstrap nesting, shows on page but not on print

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cant seem to get this right, i made a divider through css divs and it shows on page but when in print the lines i made doesnt show..what other options should i do? im running out of ideas, what am i doing wrong how can i achieve this

here is what i want ot achieve
[image: heres what i want to achieve]

heres my css
                  [image: here you see the line is visible]

heres the print preview
                   [image: heres the print preview]

page code:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p style="text-align:center;"><b>PROPERTY ACKNOWLEDGEMENT RECEIPT</b></p>
        <p style="text-align:right;">Control No.</p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-16">
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" class="">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Quantity</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Unit</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Description</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Unit Value</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Property No.</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>bucket</td>
                  <td style="font-size:12px;">oremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlorem</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr style="background-color:black;"> NOTE:
      <div style="height:2px;width:100%;background-color:black;"></div>
      <div style="width:2px;height:100px;background-color:black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
    responsive: true
  });
});
```

Comment: your media query is doing this mischief , check media queries.

Comment: i dont have an @media query..

Comment: You should user `border`s instead of this `background-color` trick.

Comment: well that did the trick!thanks!